# Python - Group duplicates in a list of lists by index

Tags: python, list

I've seen a lot of questions about removing duplicates from a list and counting them. But I'm trying to find the best way to group them - for a list of lists.

Given this example I want to group by the third field:

```
[[1, "text", "name1", "text"],
 [2, "text", "name2", "text"],
 [3, "text", "name2", "text"],
 [4, "text", "name1", "text"]]
```

I'd like to get this:

```
[[[1, "text", "name1", "text"],
  [4, "text", "name1", "text"]],
 [[2, "text", "name2", "text"],
  [3, "text", "name2", "text"]]]
```

I can think of the naive way by looping through and just keeping track of what is found (O(n^2)). But I would assume there's a better way.

Answer (score 4):

You could sorted and use groupby but that is `O(n log n)`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
from itertools import groupby

print([list(v) for _,v in groupby( sorted(l,key=itemgetter(2)),itemgetter(2))])
```

Or use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) grouping by the third element for an `O(n)` solution by using the third element as the key and appending the sublists as values. setdefault will handle the repeated keys:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

od = OrderedDict()

for sub in l:
    od.setdefault(sub[2],[]).append(sub)
from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(od.values())
[[[1, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], [4, 'text', 'name1', 'text']],
[[2, 'text', 'name2', 'text'], [3, 'text', 'name2', 'text']]]
```

If order does not matter you can use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) in place of the OrderedDict.

If order does not matter a defaultdict is by far the most efficient.

```
In [7]: from itertools import groupby

In [8]: from collections import OrderedDict, defaultdict                               

In [9]: l = [[1, "text", "name{}".format(choice(list(range(2000)))), "text"] for _ in xrange(40000)]

In [13]: from operator import  itemgetter

In [14]: timeit [list(v) for _,v in groupby( sorted(l,key=itemgetter(2)),itemgetter(2))]
10 loops, best of 3: 42.5 ms per loop

In [15]: %%timeit                                                                       
od = defaultdict(list)
for sub in l:
    od[sub[2]].append(sub)
   ....: 
100 loops, best of 3: 9.42 ms per loop

In [16]: %%timeit                                                                       
od = OrderedDict()
for sub in l:
     od.setdefault(sub[2],[]).append(sub)
   ....: 
10 loops, best of 3: 25.5 ms per loop

In [17]: lists = l

In [18]: %%timeit
   ....: groupers = set(l[2] for l in lists)
   ....: [filter(lambda x: x[2] == y, lists) for y in groupers]
   ....: 

1 loops, best of 3: 8.48 s per loop

In [19]: timeit l = [filter(lambda x: x[2] == y, lists) for y in   set(l[2] for l in lists)]
1 loops, best of 3: 8.29 s per loop
```

So if order does not matter then defaultdict wins, groupby still performs pretty well as sort is still pretty cheap in comparison to a quadratic approach. As you can see filter's quadratic complexity performs badly as the data grows.

Comment: `for _,v in groupby` would be better!

Comment: @Kasra, yep. Too used to checking `if k`!

Comment: If the key items aren't just repeated and if you randomly shuffle the list first, I think groupby loses the speed test. It did for me.

Comment: How do the sublists look like?

Comment: @StefanPochmann, yes, you were right, still pretty efficient when order matters. Actually makes sense as I was dubious as to how the filter was doing so well.

Comment: Yeah, I got similar results, with defaultdict fastest. I also like its code best, so it's my winner.

Comment: @StefanPochmann, yes, defaultdict is often faster, I have added answers where it has beaten numpy and pandas in certain situations, the only thing in this instance that would go against it would  be if the Order matters, either way worst case the OP can use the OrderedDict which still give a linear solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
>>> lists = [[1, "text", "name1", "text"],
...  [2, "text", "name2", "text"],
...  [3, "text", "name2", "text"],
...  [4, "text", "name1", "text"]]
>>> groupers = set(l[2] for l in lists)
>>> groupers
set(['name2', 'name1'])
>>> l = [filter(lambda x: x[2] == y, lists) for y in groupers]
>>> pprint.pprint(l)
[[[2, 'text', 'name2', 'text'], [3, 'text', 'name2', 'text']],
 [[1, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], [4, 'text', 'name1', 'text']]]
```

You can of course write the whole grouping logic in a single line:

```
>>> l = [filter(lambda x: x[2] == y, lists) for y in set(l[2] for l in lists)]
>>> pprint.pprint(l)
[[[2, 'text', 'name2', 'text'], [3, 'text', 'name2', 'text']],
 [[1, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], [4, 'text', 'name1', 'text']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` with element you want to sort on as `key` and `itertools groupby` to  group 'em:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> sl = sorted(your_list, key=lambda your_list: your_list[2])
>>> [list(v) for k,v in groupby(sl, key=lambda sl:sl[2])]
[[[1, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], 
  [4, 'text', 'name1', 'text']], 
 [[2, 'text', 'name2', 'text'], 
  [3, 'text', 'name2', 'text']]]
```

Comment: Yes, that sorts it. What about the grouping?

Comment: didn't pay attention to grouping, you can use itertools groupby; updated the solution..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of doing that is with the `key` argument of the `sorted()` function. In your example:

`>>> a = [[1, "text", "name1", "text"],
         [2, "text", "name2", "text"],
         [3, "text", "name2", "text"],
         [4, "text", "name1", "text"]]`

`>>> sorted(a[:], key=lambda item:item[2])`

`>>> [[1, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], 
     [4, 'text', 'name1', 'text'], 
     [2, 'text', 'name2', 'text'], 
     [3, 'text', 'name2', 'text']]`

You can find more information about this argument on [this link](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: Where's the grouping?

Comment: Yes but that just sorts it. I think you'd need to groupby() next

Answer (score 0):

The following function will quickly (**no sorting** required) group sub-sequences of **any length** by a key of **specified index**:

```
# given a sequence of sequences like [(3,'c',6),(7,'a',2),(88,'c',4),(45,'a',0)],
# returns a dict grouping sequences by idx-th element - with idx=1 we have:
# if merge is True {'c':(3,6,88,4),     'a':(7,2,45,0)}
# if merge is False {'c':((3,6),(88,4)), 'a':((7,2),(45,0))}
def group_by_idx(seqs,idx=0,merge=True):
    d = dict()
    for seq in seqs:
        if isinstance(seq,tuple): seq_kind = tuple
        if isinstance(seq,list): seq_kind = list
        k = seq[idx]
        v = d.get(k,seq_kind()) + (seq[:idx]+seq[idx+1:] if merge else seq_kind((seq[:idx]+seq[idx+1:],)))
        d.update({k:v})
    return d
```

In the case of your question, the key is the element having index 2, therefore

```
group_by_idx(your_list,2,False)
```

gives

```
{'name1': [[1, 'text', 'text'], [4, 'text', 'text']],
 'name2': [[2, 'text', 'text'], [3, 'text', 'text']]}
```

which is not exactly the output you asked for, but might as well suit your needs.